# ¿Cómo invertir cada palabra de una frase, sin invertir toda la frase?

Tags: javascript

bueno ya he intentado de todo y no logro cumplir con el objetivo, por ejemplo:

```
var str = 'Me gusta tomar mucha agua';
var newArray = str.split(' ')
var resp = '';

for(var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++){
resp += newArray[i].split('').reverse().join('');
}
console.log(resp);//eMatsugramotahcumauga
```

Mi funcion imprime: 'eMatsugramotahcumauga'; pero no logro separar las palabras invertidas, eso es lo unico que me falta,lo pude hacer pero de una forma que no es la optima como esta:

```
var str = 'Me gusta tomar mucha agua';
var separador = str.split(' ');
var resp1 = separador[0].split('').reverse().join('');
var resp2 = separador[1].split('').reverse().join('');
var resp3 = separador[2].split('').reverse().join('');
var resp4 = separador[3].split('').reverse().join('');
var resp5 = separador[4].split('').reverse().join('');
console.log(`${resp1} ${resp2} ${resp3} ${resp4} ${resp5}`)//eM atsug ramot ahcum auga
```

he intentado de todo, he leido documentacion y no encuentro la forma de optimizar mi codigo, ayuda!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pero si lo tienes casi hecho, en vez de ocupar un string (resp) ocupas un array y luego un join con un espacio

```js
var str = 'Me gusta tomar mucha agua';
var newArray = str.split(' ')
var resp = [];

for(var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++){
resp.push( newArray[i].split('').reverse().join(''));
}
console.log(resp.join(' '));
```

Comment: Arrays y push... Cómo no se me ocurrió, estuve tan cerca...

Answer (score 2):

Al hacer la separación de palabras con split usaste (correctamente) el espacio.

Ahora necesitas invertir el proceso al unir con join:

```js
let str = 'Me gusta tomar mucha agua';
let resultado = str.split(' ')
  .map(palabra => palabra.split('').reverse().join(''))
  .join(' ');

console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: No sé me había ocurrido plantearlo con map,  solo tres lines crack!

Comment: @Miltonext Gracias por tu colaboración :-) Aquí todos somos iguales y colaboradores del sitio. Tanto los que preguntan como los que responden.Quizás no te leístes el [tour], pero cuando ví tu perfil vi que tenias la medalla de **Informado** que indica que pasastes por esa página hasta el final (sino no te la dan).  Otra cosa sería con la atención que te la lelste (lo sé, cuando yo entré me la leí en diagonal igual que tu, hasta que me empezaron a advertir de mis fallos y tuve que prestale más atención).Cuando he dicho **antiguo** es porque eres más viejo que yo en el lugar (10 meses llevo) :-)

Comment: Cuando termines de leer mi comentario puedes limpiar los tuyos referentes a este tema, al igual que acabo de hacer yo (no me gusta dejar estos comentarios para siempre porque estropean las preguntas/respuestas y son offtopic, pero necesarios para el buen funcionamiento del sitio en determinados casos).  De nuevo, muchas gracias por participar y colaborar!  Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacer algo así:

```js
    var str = "Me gusta tomar mucha agua";
    var arrayFromStr = str.split(" ");
    var result = [];
    
    for (const word of arrayFromStr) {
      result.push(word.split("").reverse().join(""));
    }
    
    console.log(result.join(" ")); // Devuelve "eM atsug ramot ahcum auga"
```